# divs on left and right side

Tags: html, css

a bit vague. I use news system, on left side i want to get news from world, on right i wont to get news from my country. I really don't know how  to solve this problem:http://i48.tinypic.com/15rxzkw.jpg

source:

```
<div style="width:1000px;">
    <div style="border:1px solid red;float:left;width:400px;">news from world</div><br/><br/>

 <div style="border:1px solid red;float:left;width:400px;">news from world</div><br/><br/>

  <div style="border:1px solid red;float:left;width:400px;">news from world</div><br/><br/>

   <div style="border:1px solid red;float:left;width:400px;">news from world</div><br/> <br/>

   <div style="border:1px solid red;float:left;width:400px;">news from world</div><br/><br/>


    <div style="border:1px solid red;float:left;width:400px;">news from world</div><br/><br/>
    <div style="border:1px solid blue;width:400px;float:right;">news from my country</div><br/><br/>
    <div style="border:1px solid blue;width:400px;float:right;">news from my country</div><br/><br/>
    <div style="border:1px solid blue;width:400px;float:right;">news from my country</div><br/><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a to clear your floating divs. Put this :

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

For example:

```
<div style="width:1000px;">
<div style="border:1px solid red;float:left;width:400px;">aaaaaaaa</div>
<div style="border:1px solid blue;width:400px;float:right;">bbbbbbb</div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
<div style="border:1px solid blue;width:400px;float:left;top:0px;">cccccccc</div>
<div style="border:1px solid blue;width:400px;float:right;">dddddddddd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: imagine that i have two column/side. On left side i get all news from world, on right side i get all news news from local country. I use foreach loop, how to position div on left side if news come from world, or posotion to right side if news from local country? Do you understand?

Comment: probably two loops, one for the world news, one for local news. put all of the world news in a float: left div, all of the local news in a float: right div, and do clear: both after

Comment: wless, why are you using inline-styles btw? Try to leep html, css and javascript separated.

Comment: I kept the example I was using similar to the code he provided. But you're absolutely right, should never inline like this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the `<br /><br />`

Remove them because they push element 2,3 and 4 2 rules down.

Also try to separate styles from your html and never use `<br />` for styling. (W3C semantics)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
    <div style="width:1000px;">

   <div style="float:left;">
    <div style="border:1px solid red;width:400px;">aaaaaaaa</div><br/><br/>
    <div style="border:1px solid blue;width:400px;">bbbbbbb</div>
    </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
    <div style="border:1px solid blue;width:400px;top:0px;">cccccccc</div>
    <div style="border:1px solid blue;width:400px;">dddddddddd</div>
    </div>

    </div>
```